# javascript how to sort strings containing comma separated values

Tags: javascript, string, comparison

I would like to know how can I sort strings in javascript containing comma separated values in different order e.g.

```
    var str1 ="aaa,SC,AAA,mc,mc,aaa";
    var str2 ="AAA,SC,aaa,aaa,mc,mc";
```

So basically i want to sort them and do an equality comparion check.

```
    if(str1==str2)
    // do something...
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
str.split(",").sort().join(",")
```

Comment: That use case works, what if Str1="aaa,SC,140,mc,22,aaa"; str2 ="140,SC,aaa,aaa,mc,22"; mean numbers as string will that work as. Also what if each of them is empty?

Comment: I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work with numbers or empty strings.  You should try it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function areSame(csv1, csv2) {
    return csv1.split(",").sort().join() === csv2.split(",").sort().join();
}

var str1 = "aaa,SC,AAA,mc,mc,aaa";
var str2 = "AAA,SC,aaa,aaa,mc,mc";

alert("areSame = " + areSame(str1, str2));
```